# swift 1.2 - literal representation of recursive data structure

Tags: xcode, swift, recursion

As part of my effort to learn Xcode/Swift, I am building an app to keep track of Stuff.

I'm a big fan of hierarchal structures. My data scheme has a class called "Item" which tracks name, description, and so forth. Item has a subclass called "Container" which adds a field to contain other Items and Containers. This is a Core Data project, but that isn't relevant to this question.

I should note that I'm taking a test-driven, bottom-up approach. Right now I'm working on the fundamental data structures and methods for recording and fetching data, saving the UI for later.

The problem that I have relates to the recursive nature of the data structure. Everything worked until I introduced recursion into my test data.

This is the data description of my test data block, which succeeds for Items and empty Containers.

```
[(cType: String, content: [String: AnyObject?] )]
```

It is an array of tuples, with each tuple representing an Item/Container record. `cType` is a String to signal whether the dictionary in `content` represents an Item or a Container. (I know that `cType` should be some sort of enum, but that's not the *big* issue here.)

In the content dictionary, the values are all strings with one exception: `Container`s have a field called `contained_items`, whose value is represented by the same structure described above... another array of `(cType,content)` tuples.

I've learned elsewhere on SO that the only structure to support recursion is a class. I've come close to success by creating such a class, but I still can't express it literally.

Consider the following:

```
    func loadDataSet() -> [(cType: String, content: [String: AnyObject?] )]
    {
        return
            [
                (cType: "Container", content: ["name":"Attic of the gods","item_description":"The innavigable realm of random stuff"]) // empty Container
                ,(cType: "Item", content: ["name":"Thing","item_description":"I am a weird thing"])
                // next, a Container with contained items
                ,(cType: "Container", content: ["name":"Cardboard box","item_description":"I am a box full of stuff","contained_item":
                      [
                          (cType: "Item", content: ["name":"Doo-dad","item_description":"I am a doo-dad of some sort"])
                      ]
                ])
             ]
    }
```

At the top level, that block has three elements. The first two load successfully, but the Container with a contained_item generates a syntax error (cannot convert return expression of type '[(cType: String, content: [String: AnyObject?] )]' to expected return type '[(cType: String, content: [String: AnyObject?] )]')

So my questions are:

1: Is there a way to define a structure such as this? To not only have a class that potentially contains itself, but can also be represented in a way that's attempted above?

2: Is there a better data type than `AnyObject?` for the value of dictionary items? I'd like to narrow it down, and say (in some way) that it can be a `String`, or `[(cType: String, content: [String: AnyObject?] )]`. The docs suggest that I may be able to do some magic with enums, but I don't have my brain wrapped around that quite yet.

3: I'm working in Swift 1.2 right now, and I understand that Swift 2 supports recursive enums. Are the new features of Swift 2 compelling enough to jump to it now, or should I wait until it's out of beta? (This project is not likely to be released before the new versions of Xcode and Swift.)

Thanks to all who read this far, and thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, all the three elements generate a syntax error and it is not a recursion problem. The issue is that swift String and swift Dictionary are structs, not classes.

A struct cannot be cast to `AnyObject?` but can be cast to `Any?`.

If you change your func declaration to

```
func loadDataSet() -> [(cType: String, content: [String: Any?] )]
```

your sample code will compile successfully.

Comment: If I comment out the third element, Swift is (relatively) happy.

Comment: I see. Commenting out the third element will work in Swift 1.2 but will fail Swift 2.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I was hoping it was some sort of a simple rookie mistake. So today I learned the difference between AnyObject and Any. After replacing the data signature thru the codebase, my tests are once again succeeding. Now I can get back to moving the ball up the field (sorry if you don't get the American football metaphor). Cheers.

Comment: Recursion is still a problem... The dataSet loads, but in the import routine that digests it, top-level items import properly, but the contained_item fails. Instead of being recognized as another `[(cType: String, content: [String: Any?] )]`, it's recognized simply as an Any?. I can unwrap the optional, but I can't get Swift to recognize the value as the type I expect. (Should this comment be a new question?)

Comment: @ObbieZ, yes! :-) the answer would most likely be in to use optional casting of the Any? variable.